# Is there an elementary proof that distal maps are invertible?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, topological-dynamics

Let $T: X \to X$ be a continuous map on a compact metric space $X$. We say $T$ is distal if $\inf_n d(T^n x, T^n y) = 0$ implies $x = y$.

Then it is true that $T$ is bijective.

**Question:** Is there an elementary proof of this fact? (Injectivity clearly follows, surjectivity is the issue.) The two proofs I know go through the enveloping semigroup, and the Stone-Čech compactification $\beta \mathbb N$ respectively.

Comment: That's a very nice result. Do you have a reference for the Stone Cech compactification proof?

Comment: If $T$ is not inyective, there are points $x\neq y$ such that $T(x)=T(y)$ and thus $inf_n d(T^n(x),T^n(y))=0$. I guess you ask about surjectivity?

Comment: It is! You can find the proof in Bergelson’s survey article [Ergodic Ramsey Theory - an Update](https://people.math.osu.edu/bergelson.1/ertupdatenov6.pdf). It’s on page 33.

Comment: @rpotrie Yes, surjectivity is the nontrivial part.

Comment: Wow! Very surprising. I would expect that this is a very elementary exercise.

Comment: There is a more general result that distality of a semigroup flow implies being a group.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg in which sense?

Comment: What is $X$ is say a circle or a Euclidean sphere? Is it easier then? It would be much more surprising if the result was equally difficult for a simple space.

Comment: @YCor,  well I believe the general result is for topological semigroups and  the conclusion is being a topological group.  So I suppose the continuity of the inverse is not free without further topological assumptions.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg sorry but I see what the conclusion is but not what the assumption purports to be. I'd assume part of the setting is:"let $S$ be a submonoid of $\mathrm{Homeo}(X)$, $X$ compact metric space, such that $D(x,y)=\inf_{s\in S}d(sx,sy)>0$ for all $x\neq y$. The conclusion is that something (what? certainly not $S$) is a group.

Comment: @YCor, I think the definition of distal for topological semigroups is slightly more complicated. You can find it in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.00996.pdf and the conclusion is you have a group. They show the whole enveloping semigroup is a group as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yesser than I thought. I mentioned this issue at http://eventos.cmm.uchile.cl/edynamicsxiii/, since the proximality lemma from my previous answer was discussed there. Someone pointed out that Hindman's original proof of his famous theorem is at least somewhat elementary in some technical sense, and implies a significant part of the proximality theorem, so the answer must be "yes" at least in some technical sense.

After a bit of searching I found the relevant paper [1]: in the sense of reverse mathematics, your theorem is provable in $\mathrm{ACA}_0^+$, a certain fragment of second-order arithmetic.

I quote the relevant theorem in the form stated in this paper. They call this the Auslander-Ellis theorem.

> Theorem. Let $X$ be a compact metric space and let $T : X \to X$ be continuous. Regard $(X,T)$ as dynamical system. Given $x \in X$, there exists $y \in X$ such that $y$ is uniformly recurrent and proximal to $x$.

They show that this theorem is provable in $\mathrm{ACA}_0^+$. Let me recall how to conclude your result (this deduction seems very elementary, so I guess it needs much less than $\mathrm{ACA}_0^+$).

> Corollary. Every distal system is invertible.

Proof. Injectivity is clear. Take $x \in X$, and apply the previous theorem, to get that $x$ is proximal to some uniformly recurrent $y$. Then $x = y$, so every point in $X$ is uniformly recurrent. Clearly this implies surjectivity, since if $U$ is a neighborhood of any $x \in X$, we have $T^n(x) \in U$ for some positive $n$, and then $T^{n-1}(x)$ maps to $U$ in $T$, so $TX$ is dense in $X$ and by compactness is equal to $X$. Square.

I am not an expert, but as far as I understand, second-order arithmetic in itself is weaker than Zermelo-Frankel set theory (without choice), and $\mathrm{ACA}_0^+$ is about medium strength as far as the most commonly studied fragments of second-order arithmetic go. Roughly, the logic $\mathrm{ACA}_0$ says that a set of natural numbers exists if you can define it by an arithmetical formula, and $\mathrm{ACA}_0^+$ adds the $\omega$th Turing jump of each set already definable.

Nevertheless, to quote [1], "It is well known that all existing proofs of HT are nonconstructive. One of the goals of this paper is to delimit the degree of nonconstructivity which is inherent in Hindman's Theorem."

To summarize the logical connections obtained: Write AET for the theorem about proximality, HT for Hindman's theorem, DT for OP's theorem about distal systems. We have
$$\mathrm{ACA_0^+} \implies \mathrm{AET} \implies \mathrm{HT} \implies \mathrm{ACA_0} \wedge \mathrm{DT}$$
Intuitively (and again I am not an expert), if you believe results of a certain flavor of infinite computation are well-defined, you can prove AET and therefore the theorem about distal systems. But in theory, the problem about distal systems could be much easier (I have a hard time imagining a proof not going through proximal pairs, but I've been wrong before). In the reverse math framework, one could ask if it is in $\mathrm{ACA}_0$, or $\mathrm{WKL}_0$, or $\mathrm{RCA}_0$, in decreasing order of strength.

Reference

[1]: *Blass, Andreas R.; Hirst, Jeffry L.; Simpson, Stephen G.*, Logical analysis of some theorems of combinatorics and topological dynamics, Logic and combinatorics, Proc. AMS-IMS-SIAM Conf., Arcata/Calif. 1985, Contemp. Math. 65, 125-156 (1987). [ZBL0652.03040](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0652.03040).

Comment: Wow. So the logic stuff is a little bit beyond me, but I guess it means something like the proofs are not “that” nonconstructive? Maybe it implies something about how large the spaces used in the proof have to be. Though I’m way out of my league here so I’ll just keep wondering for now.

Comment: Second-order arithmetic means that you can only talk about sets of natural numbers in the proof. For the proximality theorem, the proof through Ellis semigroup and the proof in Auslander's book talk about subsets of some uncountable set, so they are not directly formalizable in this language. Of course you'll have to encode your system into sets of numbers to even be able to talk about the _statement_ of the theorem, and sometimes there are encoding issues, but I guess not in this case since it was not discussed in the introduction of the paper.

Answer (score 8):

It is a very nice result ! Let me try an "elementary" answer.

Define $\delta: X\times X \to \mathbb R_+$ by
$$\delta(x,y)= \inf_{n\in \mathbb N} d(T^n(x), T^n(y))~.$$
This function is continuous and vanishes exactly on the diagonal by distality.

**Edit:** *This function is NOT continuous in general, as pointed out in the comments.*

Set
$$F= \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} T^n(X)~.$$
$F$ is compact and for all $x\in X$ we have $d(T^n(x), F) \underset{n\to +\infty} \longrightarrow 0$. Since
$$\inf_{y\in F} \delta(x,y) \leq \inf_{y\in F} d(T^n(x),y)$$ for all $n$, we conclude that
$$\inf_{y\in F} \delta(x,y) = 0~.$$

By compactness of $F$ and distality, we conclude that $x\in F$ for all $x$. Hence $F=X$ and $T$ is surjective.

**Edit:** *Of course this last line falls appart if $\delta$ is not continuous. So the question is: why is the infimum $\inf_{y\in F} \delta(x,y) = 0$ is attained ?*

Comment: Hmm, maybe I’m missing something - is it obvious that $\delta$ is continuous? Naively this is a pointwise infimum of continuous functions which need not be continuous..

Comment: The Cantor set $2^{\mathbb N}$ with  its usual metric saying two infinite words are close if they have a long common prefix and the shift map $T$ (eliminating the first letter of an infinite word) is a counterexample to $\delta$ being continuous.  let $z$ be a fixed infinite word over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$ and consider the sequences of infinite words  $u_n=0^nz$ and $v_n=1^nz$.  Then $u_n$ converges to $0^{\infty}$ and $v_n$ converges to $1^{\infty}$.  Clearly $\delta(u_n,v_n)=0$ all $n$ since $T^n(u_n)=T^n(v_n)$ but $\delta(0^\infty,1^\infty)\neq 0$.

Comment: The question is, does the sentence parse as "(This function is continuous and vanishes on the diagonal) by distality." or as "This function is continuous and (vanishes on the diagonal by distality)."? @BenjaminSteinberg's example is for the latter reading.

Comment: @VilleSalo, hopefully the OP will chime in on which interpretation was meant and if the former, explain why.  I’m not a dynamics person so I don’t know distal flows to check for counterexamples.  Symbolic dynamics is my dynamical limit.

Comment: Right. Well, actually I suppose the most basic example of rotating points on a disk by their distance from the center is a counterexample. Using the unit disk of $\mathbb{C}$ as the model, $\delta(x, y) = 2$ for $x,y$ on the boundary, but nearby it can be arbitrarily small, just take two points on different circles.

Comment: @isnt this essentially a Sturmian shift? The argument about $\delta$ being continuous would be fine if the powers of T are equicontinuous but apparently distal is weaker than equicontinuous.

Comment: No not a Sturmian. You have a rotation on each individual concentric circle of radius $r$, and the point is that these circles rotate at different speeds. This is $(r, \theta) \mapsto (r, \theta+r)$ in polar coordinates. (Sorry, my description was misleading, you have to rotate the *angles* by the distance.)

Comment: This system is obviously distal (since it can be written as a disjoint union of rotations, which are distal minimal systems), and it is not equicontinuous because two points that are very close but on different circles diverge slowly.

Comment: For equicontinuous to imply distal you also need T injective I suppose

Comment: @VilleSalo your edited description is clearer

Comment: As pointed out in the comments, I was too quick to assert that $\delta$ is continuous. So there is really nothing to save...

Comment: Recently I took an introductory course on topological dynamics, and this was (mistakenly) one of the exercises there. The intended "proof" was precisely this, so at least you're not the first person to make this error :)

Answer (score 7):

**edit**

My appeal to authority in the following answer makes no sense, because it seems Auslander's flows are actually assumed to be invertible. My own intuition is still that the issue is the same, so I'll keep this for now.

**original**

I also did not understand why $\delta$ is continuous in the answer of Nicolas Tholozan, maybe they will clarify and I'll delete this, but in the meantime, I would have guessed this has no known elementary proof (or at least didn't in '88...) for the following reason: The only proof I can see is through the following theorem on page 67 in Auslander's '88 book Minimal Flows and their Extensions (in the chapter on distal flows):

> Let $(X, T)$ be a flow and let $x \in X$. Then there is an almost periodic point $x^*$ which is proximal to $x$.

Your result easily follows, because the almost periodic point will be in the eventual image. Auslander makes the following comment after the theorem:

"Every known proof of this theorem requires the use of a "large" product space (another proof will be given in the next chapter). It would be interesting to find a direct proof."

I don't see a reduction of this to the result you are after, so possibly yours is easier, but this was the only reasonable approach I could see. I also don't know if Auslander's comment has already been addressed somewhere, I am not an expert on distality by any means.

Comment: This recent paper by Auslander https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.00996.pdf is still using Ellis semigroups for the more general case of distal flows of semigroups but I didn’t see any statement that other methods are known.