# Surjectivity for distal continuous functions on a compact metric space

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, topological-dynamics

Where can I find a proof that a distal continuous function of a compact metric space is surjective?

PS:
The person asking the question [Is there an elementary proof that distal maps are invertible?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393648/) says he knows two proofs that use the enveloping semigroup, and the Stone-Čech compactification. I am interested in the references where I can find those proofs

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393648/is-there-an-elementary-proof-that-distal-maps-are-invertible

Comment: The person asking the question says he knows two proofs  that use the enveloping semigroup, and the Stone-Čech compactification. I am interested in the references where I can find those proofs.

Comment: Then I have added a "reference-request" tag.

Comment: Maybe look here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.00996.pdf#page11

Answer (score 1):

OP here! The Stone Cech proof can be found on page 33 of Bergelson’s [survey](https://people.math.osu.edu/bergelson.1/ertupdatenov6.pdf) on Ergodic Ramsey theory.

The enveloping semigroup proof can be found on page 60 of Brown’s book *Topological Dynamics and Ergodic Theory*.

Comment: Thank you, indeed i found the proofs in those references, furthermore, in the Bergelson’s survey the author refers to the article "Ebrahim Salehi and David B. Ellis. Problems and Solutions: Solutions: Revivals: 6612. Amer. Math. Monthly". Where we can found the enveloping semigroup proof .